# How can I strip HTML tags from views filter autocomplete labels?

Tags: views, 8

I have an autocomplete widget option. A view is created with exposed filter for free tagging with autocomplete option. However the results provided via suggestions when entering a tag has HTML tags, in particular `<p>` or `<strong>` tag.

[image]

Is there a way that the tags can be stripped off and trim number of characters?